# Eclipse Bug and It's Not Sorting Images Correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, image, oracle, png

Here's what my Package Explorer view looks like in Eclipse.. WRONG ORDER.

[image: Wrong order]

Here's what it looks like in the normal folder view.. CORRECT ORDER
[[image: Correct order[2]]

I'm trying to get all my images into my project but without messing up the order which it should be in ascending order but after the value passes 10 or so it bugs out and relocates some of the images to the same weird location every time and I think it is definitely a bug but I don't know why this is happening.. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The images are order according to their name and the sorting is done according to string not as numbers.

Since the names are in String format for eg : "100" ," 25" and not 100 and 25, eclipse interprets those as Strings and not numbers and hence sorts with the first character of the string i.e. "1" , "2".

So after the sorting it would always look like "1, 10, 100, 2, 25, 3, 31 " and so on. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Well in the folder is sorts fine but in Eclipse it does not. Can you help me figure out this problem?

Comment: @Pritam is correct. the problem is windows explorer is doing something weird. Either it's ordering by date added or it has a numeric ordering, which is not common. An easy workaround is to pad your filenames with leading 0s.  0001.png, 0002.png, .... 0010.png, 0011.png.  Use an appropriate number of leading zeros for the number of files you expect to have.

Comment: Thanks Pritam and David. I will use the leading 0 method for this because I'm writing a sprite cache loader and I was reading and writing to files in string order and I thought I was doing it in numerical order but that wasn't the case. Thanks so much!